# How to see that $2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} - 1 = 2^n - 1$

Tags: exponentiation

How to see that $2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} - 1 = 2^n - 1$?

Is there a rule about adding two powers of the same base I'm not aware of?  I know that you can "add the exponents" if you are multiplying numbers of the same base, or "subtract" them if you are dividing.

Comment: No, just take $2^{n-1}$ as a common factor.

Comment: $a+a=2\cdot a$ is true for _all_ a; in this case, as the various answers have noted, you have $a=2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule is $$\underbrace{k^n+k^n+\cdots +k^n}_k=k\cdot k^n=k^1k^n=k^{1+n}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} - 1 = 2\cdot2^{n - 1}-1=2^{1+n-1}-1=2^n-1$$

Answer (score 1):

Simply $2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}=2\cdot 2^{n-1}=2^n$ which works for the base $2$ - for base three you'd need to add three times $3^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$2^{n-1} + 2^{n-1} - 1 = 2\cdot2^{n-1} - 1  = 2^n - 1$